# Understanding how GNU sed range addresses work

Tags: linux, sed, gnu

I am reading about [range addresses](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/Range-Addresses.html) in GNU sed. But I don't understand how does that exactly work, I have tried to run `sed --debug` but the output is too verbose to understand.

Let's assume that I have the following file `input.txt`:

```
===sep1

Aghroum

===sep2
Thirjeen
===sep3
Ya wedi mata ikinikh

===sep4
Ifoullissen
===sep5
```

When I try to use range addresses as follows:

```
sed -n '/=/,/=/{/=\|^$/! p}' input.txt
```

The output is:

```
# it prints non-empty lines from ===sep1 to ==sep2, and from ===sep3 to ==sep4, etc. 
Aghroum
Ya wedi mata ikinikh
```

As far as I know, GNU sed process the input file line by line, why it doesn't matches also the **range address** between `==sep2` to `==sep3`? (Please note that I am not asking how to get those lines, I know how to do that by using something like `sed -n '/===/!p'`. But I am asking why it doesn't start the second range address from `===sep2` to `===sep3`)

Thank you

Comment: because you are explicitly saying you don't want them in `/=\|^$/! p`, this matches two regexes, 1) lines containing `=` character or `|` 2) empty lines `^$`, if matched, don't print them `! p`.

Comment: @αғsнιη: I mean why the range address works only `1-2, 3-4, 5-6` but not `1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5, 5-6` ?

Comment: By design. See the [POSIX specification](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) where it states "Starting at the first line following the selected range, `sed` shall look again for the first address. Thereafter, the process shall be repeated". This is not an answer because I cannot tell why the design is what it is. The best I can think of is "because it's useful". Frankly I find this reason pretty good and sufficient. It's still my guess though.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: The closest I can find is this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24273038/13782017 but I can't comment on it (due to reputation) to ask him for a reference.

Comment: May we know what other behavior you expected?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: overlapping ranges

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is explained in [the `sed` specification in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html):

> An editing command with two addresses shall select the inclusive range from the first pattern space that matches the first address through the next pattern space that matches the second. [...] Starting at the first line following the selected range, *sed* shall look again for the first address. Thereafter, the process shall be repeated.

Once a range is found, the next range can only start from the line *following* the range, at the earliest.

Put another way, the end match in a range “consumes” the line against which it matched; that line can’t start another instance of the same range.

Answer (score 2):

`sed` will do as was requested and match from `=` to `=` as stated in the command

```
sed -n '/=/,/=/{/=\|^$/! p}' input.txt
```

`sed` reads each line at a time. This means that when the end of a range is found, it will not include that ending range as a starting range also.

Consider this;

```
===sep1

Aghroum

===sep2
```

The range will always match `Aghroum` as it has reached the end of the range match as well as the file.

With the inclusion of the remainder of the file;

```
Thirjeen
===sep3
Ya wedi mata ikinikh

===sep4
Ifoullissen
===sep5
```

The matching starts again, this time from the line with value `sep03` until the next match in the range of `=` which will output `Ya wedi mata ikinikh`.

As there is only one further match with no end to the range thereafter, there is nothing else to match within the range and thus, the matching exits